# How to find the beginning of a sentence that is similar to another using levenshtein distance in text file?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, similarity, levenshtein-distance

I need to find all the beginning of sentences in a text file, but the problem is that the sentences I am looking for in file can have a bit of diffrence with the sentences I have in an array.

I was thinking of using the levenshtein distance to compare the sentences, the problem is what do I compare with what? The file is big and the sentences are only one line at best.

till now here is my code with a simple comparaison without any similarity distance.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel("./excel_file_with_the_sentences.xlsx")
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Année', 'Journal', 'A_Sommaire', 'Numero'])
# print(df)

jo = df.query("Année == 2018")
jo.sort_values(by=['Numero'], inplace=True)
# "A_Sommaire" contains the sentences the other fields are there to filter and sort only
print(jo["A_Sommaire"])
print(len(jo))
#################################################################################

file_path = "./the_file_with_the_text.txt"

file = open(file_path)
txt = file.read()
##################################################################################

titles = [t for t in jo["A_Sommaire"]]
print(titles)
beginnings = []
for title in titles:
    # here I get the iterator that point to the first title encontred
    # and I want to change it so that it can search for the first "similar"
    # title or sentence
    beginning = re.finditer(title, txt, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    beginnings.append([b.start() for b in beginning])

print(beginnings)
```

This is the result:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [13898], [], [17136], [17645], [18743], [19886], [21010], [22165], [], [], [], [26885], [], [31049], [33333], [35260], [37339], [39760], [41822], [], [45880], [], [], [], [54839], []]
```

and this is not complete, normally there are no null because every sentence in the Excel file should be present at least once in the text file.

So my question is, How can I get all the beginning of my sentences in the text file using levenshtein distance or any other way to determine the similarity?

**Note** the files are too big to even try to take a portion for exemple purpose, so I am sorry for that.

Comment: Would it be possible to split that string at the `. ` mark ? ( a dot and a space ). That way you will get all of your sentences in an array.

Comment: i don't quite understand why. but the sentence is a bunch of words and dots , I don't particularly need the dot or the spaces i only need to know the position of the sentence in the file, so yeah it's possible to split or do anything with it.